# Question on Product Rule of the counting priciple

Tags: combinatorics

Question: How many license plate you could make if you are to use a serial of 7 figure where the first three are digits and the last four are English alphabets?

My Answer: 26 letters of alphabet and 10 digits 0-10

I used product rule here.

10 multiply 26=260 plates

Is This correct?

Comment: That would be the number of plates consisting of **one** digit followed by **one** letter.

Comment: yeap I had figured it out it should be something like this Letters:26.26.26.26=456,976 then digits: 10.10.10=1000 therefor 1000 multiply by 456976=456,976,000 plates is this correct now or not yet?

Comment: I have not checked the multiplication, but the answer in the comment is structurally right.

Comment: @Andre Nicolas, if the questions says no repetitions of digits nor alphabet letters. it will be 720 digits multiply 358,800 letters=258,336,000. is this correct?

Comment: It will be $(10)(9)(8)(26)(25)(24)(23)$. I have not done the multiplication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What product rule are you talking about?

Think of it this way: if you had 3 digits, how many numbers can you form with just 3 digits? Obviously it's more than 260 since you can have all numbers from 0-999 with 3 digits. This is formalized by picking any of the 10 digits (0-9) for each of the three digits, giving you $10^3$ possibilities. Now, imagine if you had 4 letters. You could pick any of the 26 letters for each letter, giving you $26^{4}$ possibilities.

So in all you would have $10^{3}26^{4}$ possible plates.

Comment: The OP is referring to the [Multiplication Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product), which you used to solve the problem.

Comment: Nice bro, that's perfect